# association inheritance in prolog

Tags: inheritance, prolog, rules

I am trying to have associations from an object be applicable to descendant objects for an assignment.

```
whatProperty(canary, X, Y).
```

generates *colour, yellow* but not properties that should have been inherited from bird and animal.

This section of code is supposed to mean 'If X is a Y, and Y has property Z, then X has property Z'. but it clearly isn't working for some reason

```
hasproperty(X, Z, W) :-
    isa(X, Y), hasproperty(Y, Z, W).
```

Here is the complete code:

```
isa(bird, animal).
isa(canary, bird).    

hasproperty(animal, covering, skin).
hasproperty(bird, covering, feathers).
hasproperty(bird, travel, fly).
hasproperty(canary, colour, yellow).

hasproperty(X, Z, W) :-
    isa(X, Y), hasproperty(Y, Z, W).

whatProperty(Object, X, Y) :-
    hasproperty(Object, X, Y).
```

Comment: It's working. Use an 'all solutions' builtin, or backtrack using `;`. Example: `?- findall(X/Y,whatProperty(canary,X,Y),L).
L = [colour/yellow, covering/feathers, travel/fly, covering/skin].`

Comment: How do I do backtracking with ;?

Comment: Prolog automatically backtracks when you press `;`. It backtracks seeking additional instantiations that make the query succeed.